# Debugger Canvas - similar add-on compatible with Visual Studio 2013/2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

As C# developer I found nice add-on Debugger Canvas which is supported only for Visual Studio 2010.

Does anyone know about something similar for Visual Studio 2013/2015?
Thx.

Comment: As Sergey mentioned Code Connect might be what you're looking for. It works at design time, not debug time though. And it's only for VS 2015.

Answer (score 3):

The [Code Connect](http://codeconnect.io/) extension allows you to work with individual functions, not files.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in "code bubbles" functionality of Debugger Canvas, you can try my [Task Canvas](https://vlasovstudio.com/task-canvas/) extension for Visual Studio 2015/2017.